# Ordering LinkedList <class>

Tags: java

I've created a `linkedlist<FileInfo>` - file info is class which contains following:

```
class FileInfo {
      public String Name; 
      public Long Length; 
      public Long LastModified;
      public String LockedBy;
}
```

I need to order this list based on **name** or *lastmodified*. How can I achieve this? I can't use

```
Collections.sort(actTreeFileInfoLinkdList)
```

because generic is not a string. How can I sort it? I'm new in java, so maybe there is obvious and simple answer I cant figure out, thanks :)

Comment: Pass a `Comparator<FileInfo>` to Collections.sort

Comment: so like this? Collections.sort(Comparator<FileInfo>)

Comment: No, `Collections.sort(actTreeFileInfoLinkdList,comparator)` where comparator is a `Comparator<FileInfo>`

Comment: Or implement [`Comparable<FileInfo>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in `FileInfo`.